# Pop3Client Server Not Found Exception in page load when retrieving emails to a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, pop3, inbox

I developed a simple web application to send emails by multiple users. It works as a help desk in my organization and it is up and running without any errors for couple of months now. I wanted to integrate an inbox to this application.

When the user pressed on ***inbox*** icon in menu bar, the page will retrieve and load with 1st 10 emails in the server to a grid view.

But, there is an exception as 
**An exception of type 'OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.PopServerNotFoundException' occurred in OpenPop.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Server not found**

This error comes in 
**POPcl.Connect("outlook.mydomain.local", 25, false)**.

I tried this even with my personal gmail account and still does not work. I got out from the company network and tried, but still does not work.

I tried in many ways, but could not solve this problem. Is there anyone who can help me with this. Below is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using OpenPop.Pop3;
using OpenPop.Mime;

namespace CallAdmin
{
public partial class Inbox : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        Pop3Client POPcl;
            if (Session["Pop3Client"] == null)
            {
                POPcl = new Pop3Client();
                POPcl.Connect("outlook.mydomain.local", 25, false);
                POPcl.Authenticate("email_address@mydomain.com", "Password", AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
                Session["Pop3Client"] = POPcl;
            }
            else
            {
                POPcl = (Pop3Client)Session["Pop3Client"];
            }
            int count = POPcl.GetMessageCount();
            DataTable dtMessages = new DataTable();
            dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber");
            dtMessages.Columns.Add("From");
            dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject");
            dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent");
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                Message message = POPcl.GetMessage(i);
                dtMessages.Rows.Add();
                dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["MessageNumber"] = i;
                dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["Subject"] = message.Headers.Subject;
                dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["DateSent"] = message.Headers.DateSent;
                counter++;
                if (counter > 10)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            gvInbox.DataSource = dtMessages;
            gvInbox.DataBind();
        }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems specified POP3 server can not be found or connected to, please verify your address

Comment: The error happens because the server outlook.mydomain.local cannot be reached. Try with a real server and I guess it should work.

Comment: ... and also check the port. Port 25 is very unusual for POP3

Comment: @programtreasures mail account can be accessed with the Outlook web app. All the other emails are coming and going from that account without any error.

Comment: @LAHIRUSANDARUWAN there might be cause of firewall of your internal network?

Comment: @Isma I tried with my personal gmail account. But did not work.

Comment: @SirRufo Port 25 is the port given by the company. All the other emails are accessing through that Port without any issue.

Comment: @programtreasures I also thought about that at first and tried this out of the company's network but still I get the same error.

Comment: Hmm, which port do you use with your gmail account?

Comment: @SirRufo Now it's working with Gmail. I use port 995. But still not working with the organization's email address. Seems to be the problem is with the email account.

Comment: Ask for the right port you have to use for the organization imap service. There are some that could be used. Well known are 143 or 993 but they do not have to (see gmail).

Comment: 25 is the SMTP port.  It's almost assuredly not the right port to fetch email.